# Removing space between images

Tags: html, css

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QibM0.png)I have a block of images but they are not connected to one another, I need to remove the spaces and make them looked attached. I have tried the following but doesn't work

```
img {
 border: 0 none;
box-shadow: none;
padding:0px;
float: left;
display:block;
float:left;
line-height:0;
}
```

This is my html

```
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 ">
            <div class="hovereffect">
             <img src="images/plasma.jpg" alt="Plasma" id="space">
            <div class="overlay">
           <h3>
           <a href="#" class="link">Creativity on Combined Photos</a>
           </h3>
            <p> 
                <a href="#" class="link">LINK HERE</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
      </div> 
      </div>
```

Please see the image where the problem is.

Comment: What is the margin set to?

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0` ?

Comment: please post the html code

Comment: Yes I have tried margin:0px

Comment: There's only one image in the HTML provided. Please provide at least two so that we can see the problem. Preferably, use Stack Snippets (the icon looks like a page with angle brackets), or jsfiddle.net so that we can run the code in a sandbox.

Comment: Please check this jsfiddle link:https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18774/

Comment: I have put an image link where the problem is. Please check

Comment: I think it's because the images have different pixel dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.test{
  display:flex
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
            <div class="hovereffect">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            <div class="overlay">
           <h3>
           <a href="#" class="link">Creativity on Combined Photos</a>
           </h3>
            <p> 
                <a href="#" class="link">LINK HERE</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="hovereffect">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            <div class="overlay">
           <h3>
           <a href="#" class="link">Creativity on Combined Photos</a>
           </h3>
            <p> 
                <a href="#" class="link">LINK HERE</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
      </div> 
      </div>
```

is it something like this you are looking for?

I did this with flexbox you just give the parent of the images display:flex;

if you not want them one next to each other you can do it this way

```css
.test{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column
}
.hovereffect{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
            <div class="hovereffect">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            <div class="overlay">
           <h3>
           <a href="#" class="link">Creativity on Combined Photos</a>
           </h3>
            <p> 
                <a href="#" class="link">LINK HERE</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="hovereffect">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            <div class="overlay">
           <h3>
           <a href="#" class="link">Creativity on Combined Photos</a>
           </h3>
            <p> 
                <a href="#" class="link">LINK HERE</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
      </div> 
      </div>
```

Comment: Yes this is the way I want, is it possible to have the images at the bottom too connected in the same way?

Comment: This doesn't work when working with bootstrap row and column

Comment: what exectly you mean? they not the same height? and you want them to be on the same line on the bottom of the two images?

Comment: sorry for Bootstrap i can't help you i don't work with it

Comment: Thanks, I will use this to create it

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
img {
border: 0 none;
box-shadow: none;
padding:0px;
float: left;
display:block;
margin:0;
line-height:0;
}
```

Comment: this was already discussed in the comments, where it should be discussed. An answer should be used when you know the answer will work, not when you are guessing...